# SQL Left Outer Join causes Msg 4145 (non-boolean where boolean expected)

Tags: sql, join, ssms

I'm new here so if I do something that breaks convention please let me know.

I am trying to create a simple query that includes a single outer join before I move onto a larger and more complicated query. When I run my query before adding the join it works as expected. When I add the join the query returns an error message. I cannot determine the cause of the error. I am working in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

This query runs successfully and produces the expected results:

```
use MyDatabase
select table1.ID_NUM,
table1.LAST_NAME
From table1,
table2
where table1.id_num = table2.id_num
```

This query does not run successfully:

```
use MyDatabase
select table1.ID_NUM,
table1.LAST_NAME
From table1,
table2
where table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id_num = table2.id_num
```

The error message I get is:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'left'.
```

I also tried "outer join" instead of "left outer join", but this produced a similar error message (the only difference was "near 'outer'" instead of "near 'left'").

I do know what boolean means but I am not sure why it's an issue here. The boolean operator comes later in the same line. My code looks like it follows the same format as other code I have seen. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your join needs to be after the FROM not in the WHERE clause

```
use MyDatabase
select table1.ID_NUM,
table1.LAST_NAME
From table1 
left outer join table2 on table1.id_num = table2.id_num
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using deprecated syntax, listing out tables and defining their relationship in the `WHERE` clause has been replaced by explicit `JOIN` statements

```
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
 ON t1.col2 = t3.col1
```

Old style joins do allow for outer joins:

```
use MyDatabase
select table1.ID_NUM,
table1.LAST_NAME
From table1,table2
where table1.id_num *= table2.id_num
```

This old syntax should be avoided, but helpful to know what they are if you come across them.